# Getting message 'could not launch application' while launching the application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created the .ipa file of the application. I have installed it the device via iTunes. It is getting installed on the device but when I launch the application it shows the message `"Could not launch application"`. I have added the deviceId to provisioning profile. Please give me some suggestion on this.

Comment: Is there any other info you can provide? Maybe your profile that you built it with expired?

Comment: You could check out the console log for the device you're attempting to run it on. That could give some clues. Xcode -> Organizer -> Devices -> <Your Device> -> Console

Comment: try deleting all the apps running at the background on device.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me some times but it just couldn't launch the app when I get onto my device and scroll over to the screen where the app would be it is there and if I manually launch it on my own it still works... I don't know what causes it, I wish I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your same previous application from iPAD, Now delete all profile and install fresh copy of your application. i hope it seems working....

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i got while creating iPA file. I have solved issue in this way.

First of all check you have previous build in your device. Then you need to relaunch your xcode, build and clean your project using `CMD+SHIFT+K` then create iPA file and try to install in device. Make sure that you have deleted all previous instances of application and if possible then restart your device. One more thing check same provisioning profile is available in your xcode through `Organizer`.

This works fine for me.